# Spring: convert a nullable String value to Double

Tags: java, spring

I have a map of strings. I want to pull a value out of that map and pass it into another object as a Double property. It's possible that the key resolves to null. What is the best way to do this?

As an example, this fails when the value resolves to null:

```
<bean id="someBean" class="mystuff.Example">
    <property name="someDoubleProp">
        <bean class="java.lang.Double">
            <constructor-arg value="#{jobParameters['something']}" />
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
```

I'm hopefully looking for some nice SpEL expression that is the same as this java:

```
myMap.get("something") == null ? null : new Double(myMap.get("something"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use ternary operator and [static method call](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/expressions.html#d0e11977)

```
#{jobParameters['something']==null?(double)0:T(java.lang.Double).valueOf(jobParameters['something'])}
```

be carefull because, if jobParameters['something'] is not rappresenting a valid double you will get a `NumberFormatException`.
You can think to use a function like [`NumberUtils.toDouble()`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/math/NumberUtils.html#toDouble%28java.lang.String%29) that doesn't throw exception, but set a default value.

Comment: I changed the (double)0 to null, but other than that it works, thanks.